# Erro lendo arquivo binário

Tags: javascript, arquivo, binary

estou tentando ler um arquivo binário (digital biométrica) que o próprio usuário seleciona. Mas não está retornando nada.

O que está errado?

Segue código abaixo:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var campo = "";
reader.onload = function(e) {
     campo = reader.result;
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
document.getElementById('template').value = campo;
alert("CAMPO TAMANHO --> " + campo.length);
}
```

Comment: Tens um `}` a mais no teu código. Isso é mesmo assim ou foi do copy/paste?

Answer (score 2):

Sem ter o código completo pra rodar, é difícil adivinhar exatamente o que está indo errado.

Dito isso, uma coisa que está estranha no seu código é que você está lendo o valor do campo sem esperar o onload rodar primeiro. Não esperar pela callback quando o código é assíncrono é um bem erro comum.

Tente colocar o código que usa o resultado dentro do callback:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var campo = reader.result;
    document.getElementById('template').value = campo;
    alert("CAMPO TAMANHO --> " + campo.length);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```